# VBA: moving values over to another sheet based off of Vlookup results

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a code that conducts a loop on Vlookup and the intention of this is that based on the vlookup, it moves specific cells over to another specific cell but in another sheet. The code runs but it does not move the data over for some reason. I've tried another approach within the If comment and doing a range with a copy destination but I begin to get object not identified errors. Hoping someone can see what I may be missing on why the values are not getting moved over.

```
Dim i, j, lastG, lastD As Long
Dim sht, ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With
' find last row
lastG = Sheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastD = Sheets("Slide Layout").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Set sht = Sheets("Log")
Set ws = Sheets("Slide Layout")

' loop over values in "Log"
For i = 2 To lastG
    currVal = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)
    lookupval = Sheets("Log").Cells(i, "B") ' value to find
        If lookupval = currVal Then
            sht.Cells(i, "F") = ws.Cells(lastD)
        End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .CutCopyMode = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `currVal = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)` - this never changes. Also, when declaring variables, you need to specify the type each time: `Dim i As Long, j as Long, lastG As Long, lastD as Long`, otherwise the variable is a `Variant`. Same goes for `sht`.

Comment: ```ws.Cells(lastD)``` is going to return row 1 (unless lastD > 16384) and whatever column index ```lastD``` is. That probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @BigBen all of those are specified already and the currval isn't meant to change.

Comment: They are declared, but they are not the Variable type you expect them to be. I wasn't sure if `currVal` was supposed to change or not, which is why I pointed it out.

Comment: @warcupine So, I found that it goes to the exact spot I want it to with that. The problem I found is that the "lastD" is a blank cell, and the code is taking the blank cell and moving it over to replace the value. So basically it is doing it backwards for some reason.

Comment: @BigBen okay I think I get what you're saying. So would you suggest I specify again on these or what?

Comment: Yes that is best practice.

Comment: You want ```ws.cells(lastD)``` to be filled? you just need to swap the order of the equation, ```sht.Cells(i, "F") = ws.Cells(lastD)``` should be ```ws.Cells(lastD) = sht.Cells(i, "F")``` Though that shouldn't solve your object errors

Comment: @Warcupine So I tried that, but it didn't do anything for me weirdly enough.

Comment: @BigBen tried this, and I got an error "Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope"

Comment: No - swap out the line `Dim i, j, lastG, lastD As Long` and replace it with `Dim i As Long, j as Long, lastG As Long, lastD as Long`.

Comment: If ```sht.cells(i, "F")``` is blank but the criteria is met it will override the value in ```ws.cells(lastD)``` because that will never change, so the last value it meets will be stored there. Maybe thats the issue? hard to tell without seeing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, figured it out! I just replaced the

```
sht.Cells(i, "F") = ws.Cells(lastD)
```

with

```
sht.Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastD, "B")
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am following entirely...but it looks like you should have this

sht.Cells(i, "F") = currVal